# Get Page Views of a Wikipedia Page Using an API?

Tags: python, wikipedia

I'm trying to find an API that allows me to easily get the total number of views for a given wikipedia page. Does anyone know if something that does that exists for python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Pageview API](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Analytics/AQS/Pageviews). There are some examples there of how you should interact with the API via HTTP

To do this in python you could, for example, use the `requests` library. Simple example:

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia/all-access/all-agents/Albert_Einstein/daily/2015100100/2015103100')
data = resp.json()
print(data['items'][0]['views'])
```

Comment: Hi that seems to be what i'm looking for, i'm a little confused however on how do I set a user-agent header. I keep getting a 403 error which I suspect is from there ?

Comment: It's hard to help you unless you provide info about what you're trying to do. Please, show a request example or tell what kind of info you want to get

Comment: Sorry it was just me being an idiot, forgot to put in the header for my request.

Comment: Thanks, this API worked like a charm for what I wanted.